# Continue after failed command in bash script with `set -e`

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script that parses Bundler's output for errors, but I've run into an issue that I'm not certain how to handle:

```
response="$(bundle install 2>&1)"
echo $response
```

If Bundler fails, then $response is blank, and I can't parse it as I need. I've tried:

```
response="$(bundle install 2>&1 || true)"
echo $response
```

Which works, but isn't what I want because I still want my script to fail when Bundler fails.

How can I allow `bundle install` to fail and still read its output?

I should also add that I'm using `set -e`, which I need.

Edit:

After reading PSkocik's answer, this allows me to continue through the error, while still exiting when it happens:

```
response="$(bundle install 2>&1)" || bundle_status=$?
# Continue working (In my case, I'm parsing the errors to give more
# meaningful output for the context in which bundler is being run).
# And now I can exit with the given status code, or default to 0.
exit ${bundle_status:-0}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the `-e` option.
You need to make sure the error return status gets tested for:

**`man sh` on  `-e`** (`man bash` is a little more verbose on this, but in the same spirit)

> If not interactive, exit immediately if any untested command fails. 
>   The exit status of a command is considered to be explicitly tested if
>   the command is used to control an if, elif, while, or until; or if the
>   command is the left hand operand of an “&&” or “||” operator.

Here's an example with a bundler mock (in sh, but should work in bash too):

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
bundle(){
  echo "i'm errorring here" >&2
  return 32
}

response="$(bundle 2>&1)"
echo "won't get here if -e is set"
```

You can solve it like this:

```
response="$(bundle 2>&1)" || ret=$? #`set -e` won't kill us now
echo "will get here now"
echo "the bundle command exited with $ret"
echo "the response is ${response}"
```

If you need to echo strings that aren't yours, you should consider printf instead of echo (and don't forget double quotes): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: This is perfect, and thank you for the suggestion to use printf.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to get rid of `-e` and find a way to do more sophisticated error handling.

The other option is to replace the bundle command with a wrapper.  Example:

```
function my-bundle {
    set +e
    output=$(bundle "$@" 2>&1)
    ret=$?
    echo "$output" # Add code for output parsing here
    set -e
    return $ret
}

# main script
set -e
```

There is no way you can have `set -e` handle the return status of a command *and* run code after the command. (Unless you want to use `trap`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you *don't* want your script to fail when Bundler does. You just want to exit *after* you've caught the error and done something with the error message. Don't use `set -e`.

```
if ! response=$(bundle install 2>&1); then
    ret=$?
    # do something with $reponse
    exit $ret
fi
```